# How I can access to $_SESSION in Craft CMS 3.x

Tags: php, twig, craftcms

Is it possible to access to `$_SESSION` variable in `.twig` template Craft CMS `3.x` version ? I found articles about `2.5` version but nothing for `3.x+`.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Well did you try the 2.5 solution in the 3.X version then?

Comment: How this question answers to my question?

Comment: It does not, it requests more information about what've you tried so far and what errors/difficulties occurs

Comment: So thank you for that. Now I found how to access to $_SESSION variable in Craft CMS but can't access to it through ajax. If I'm trying to load Craft CMS in ajax file it returns error: `<pre>Not Found: Page not found.</pre>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session component in Craft 3 is available under `Craft::$app->session` in PHP and `craft.app.session` in twig. This returns a [`craft\web\Session`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-session.html) object corresponding to the current user's session.